# I need my two elements to have opposite transform coordinates/directions for dragging functionality

Tags: javascript

document.getElementById("element1").style.transform = document.getElementById("element2").style.transform;

The code above will move them in unison but I need them to move in opposite directions. I've tried to figure out how to multiply by -1 on the second one but I get a NAN or undefined result depending on how I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the transformation matrix using

```
var el = document.getElementById("element2");
var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
var tr = st.getPropertyValue("transform");
```

`tr` should be a string that looks like this (assuming 2D transform type)

```
matrix(0.8660254037844387, 0.49999999999999994, -0.49999999999999994, 0.8660254037844387, 0, 0)
```

then extract those 6 values which might take a bit of parsing (see link below). Multiply each element by -1 or do whatever the appropriate inverse operation is and set the new transform with

```
document.getElementById("element1").style.transform = matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

However, if you've defined the transform of `element2` yourself, then it would be much easier to just invert the input to that and define it for `element1` in the same way rather than trying to recover it from `element2`.